# Logitech Setpoint conflicting with X-Mouse Button Control?

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse, trackball, xmouse, logitech-setpoint

I use a Logitech M570 Trackball under Windows 10.  I want to simply make buttons 4 & 5 send keystrokes for a specific application.  For reasons I can't fathom, the Setpoint software simply cannot do this for this application (Sierra Chart).

X-Mouse Button Control however, does it just fine.  The problem is that if Setpoint is running, then XBC won't work.  If I quit Setpoint then XBC works perfectly, but then I lose the features of Setpoint (like smooth scrolling in particular).

I can't for the life of me figure out what the conflict is here.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?  Or a possible alternative to XBC for both remapping the 4 & 5 buttons, but also for inverting the scroll direction?

Comment: Do you need setpoint?

Comment: Yes, it is required for Smooth Scrolling to work.

Comment: If you get no answer here try the xmouse forums>>>>https://forums.highrez.co.uk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this conflict existed in the first place, but I now know how to solve it.  In Setpoint, buttons 4 & 5 must be set to "Other" and then "Generic Button".  Now everyone plays nicely together.  [Thanks to the user forum for figuring this out.](https://forums.highrez.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=4187&p=20879)